# Calling a modified value of the action destination based on form checkbox selection

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I am generating a form using php. The form has several checkbox items that user can select. The php code looks similar to this.

```
function choice_gen ($msgs, $dest) { 
    $choices = explode("\n", $msgs); 
    $index = 1; 
    $return_string = "      <div class=\"checkbox_1\">\n";
    $return_string .= "         <form method=\"post\" action=\"" . $dest . "\">\n";
    foreach ($choices as &$choice) {
      $return_string .= "            <input type=\"Checkbox\" name=\"check_list[]\" id=\"C" . $index . "\" value=\"C" . $index . "\">\n"; 
      $return_string .= "            <label for=\"C". $index . "\">$choice</label>\n";
        $return_string .= "            <BR>\n\n";

       $index++;
    }
    $return_string .= "         <input type=\"Submit\" value=\"Next\" class=\"form-submit-button\">\n";
    $return_string .= "      </form>\n";
    $return_string .= "   </div>\n";

   if (!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
      foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
         $select .=  $check; 
      }
   }
   return($return_string); 
}
```

$dest is a file name ('somefile.php'). I would like to change the action to "$dest?ch=$select" based on the user input. How do I do this using only PHP (no JS or Ajax etc.)?

Comment: It wouldn't be possible to change the URL like this, PHP is render before the user interacts with anything. Specifically this is why JS exists... But why not have the form post to one URL and carry out what ever logic you need using the posted data

Comment: @Zachary, I understand that PHP is done before the user interaction. But how do I carry the value of $select to the next page ($dest)? It seems it is lost while the action page is loaded. Essentially I want to keep a 'global variable' across several pages. I was thinking to do this by calling $dest as $dest?ch=..., but any other way is fine too.